# MYSQL double table search with variables in query

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i want to acheive the following results for the purpose of a **search script in php**
i have 2 tables like this

```
Table 1 :

-----------------------------
id  l name l url l image url  l
-------------------------------

Table 2 :
-----------------------------------
id  l tableoneid l desc l content  l
------------------------------------
```

**Note : (Table 1 --> id) = (Table 2 ---> tableoneid)**

what i want to acheive is to get a MYSQL query that search :

1. **Step 1** : The table 2 column [content] when i get the result i need
   their **[tableoneid]** values,
2. **Step 2 :** Next i want to use that in order to search the Table 1 column 1
3. **Step 3 :** The final results would be the corresponding [image url] column of the **Step 2 results**

how can i acheive that with php/mysql

thank you very much !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between INNER and OUTER joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM <Table 1>
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT(tableoneid) FROM <Table 2>
)
```

Change `<Table 1>` and `<Table 2>` with your actual table names.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the primary uses of JOINs.

```
SELECT t1.`image url`
FROM `Table 2` AS t2
INNER JOIN `Table 1` AS t1 ON t2.tableoneid = t1.id
WHERE [some condition involving t1.content]
;
```

I would **strongly** suggest not having any sort of non-alpha characters (other than `_` in your table and field names.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "select
  t1.`image url`
from
  `Table 1` as t1
join
  `Table 2` as t2 on t1.id = t2.tableoneid
where
  t2.content = :table2ContentSearch";

$statement = $dbh->prepare($query);
$searchItem = "what you are searching for";
$statement->bindParam(':table2ContentSearch', $searchItem);
if($statement->execute()){
   while($row = $statement->fetch()){
     print_r($row); 
   }
}
```

you should also read up on sql joins.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29.